# Play! Internationalization of template parameter

Tags: scala, templates, playframework, internationalization, playframework-2.0

Hell'o,

I'm using the Play! framework to build a application using Scala templates but i'm stuck on a problem ..

I have this code :

```
@template("Homepage") {
    <p>Some Content</p>  
}
```

And i'm trying to "internationalize" the parameter, i try some different possibilities like :

as a 'standard' parameter

```
@template("@Messages('homepage')")
```

through a variable

```
@defining(@Messages("homepage")) { title =>
    @template(@title) {
```

or even in the template

```
@tempate("homepage")

[... and in the template]

<title>@Message("@title")</title>
```

But no way to do it ... Each time i get compilation errors or i get the String "@Message('..')" or "@title" in the HTML page

Did someone know how to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue comes from your use of the '@' character, this character should be used once at the beginning of a statement, so instead of writing `@Message("@title")`, write `@Message(title)`.

The '@' character says to the template, this is Scala code, and once you put at the beginning of a statement you don't need to keep using it for Scala variables in the same line.

Answer (score 2):

God you rock !!

Finally i have this code that works

```
@template(Messages("homepage")) {
    <p>Some Content</p>
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help, however, for these kinds of comments, please use the comment section bellow the Answer or the Question. :-)